# External monitor displaying only noise after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, hdmi

After upgrading to Yosemite, I see just noise on the external monitor, 
using a MDP to HDMI converter and an HDMI to DVI cable. It worked very well on Mavericks. I have no display now after updating, it just shows grey noise. Tried resetting SMC & PRAM. Additionally, I have tested each of the cables individually and they are okay, so it has to be a software problem.

Display screenshot:

[image: This is what my display looks like]

It shows flickers in red color sometimes.

Macbook gives display on another setup, but flickers a lot. (my friend's) 
its a MDP to VGA adapter plugged to VGA monitor.

Mine gives no display, I'm disappointed. Need help please.

Comment: Does it show up in Display profiles in About this Mac and in ColorSync Utility app?

Comment: You're not alone. https://discussions.apple.com/message/26885684

Comment: yes it does show up everywhere

Comment: I have this same problem and have yet to find a solution.  MBAir 11" 2014, with Mavericks the external monitor via Thunderbolt to DVI worked fine, after upgrading to Yosemite I get the same thing as Usman...  My monitor works fine if connected on startup, but after sleep, or disconnect/reconnect, it goest to this noise display... annoying!

Comment: Plugging the cable out and in again fixes it for me, but that can't be a permanent solution

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the display resolution to 720p (or any else, feel free to experiment).
It might be a working solution.

**To do this follow these steps**

- Open system Preferences > Displays
- Choose lower resolution from list
- If you want a higher resolution for your external monitor, you can try to use third party software (e.g. [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/)) to change it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I almost forgot I had this issue, recently I changed cables. I am now using MDP to HDMI without adapters. Before I am using DVI to DVI Cable + DVI to MDP Adapter.

I think you need to avoid 2 conversions and use only 1 cable.

**OLD ANSWER**

It is also happening to me, and I can't find the solutions either. But I figured out **how to avoid it**.

**When booting up mac**

- turn off monitor first and then power on the mac.
- turn on the monitor after the mac finished boot or in the login screen

**Settings**

- Open system Preferences > Energy Saver
- Click Power Adapter tab(assuming your mac is plugged in) and slide the *'Turn display off after'* to at least 1 hr.

It also occurs when mac goes to sleep and to avoid it, the steps above should be followed. Only do the **settings** step if you don't mind the power consumption.

Please let me know if you have better suggestions but this works for me as of now.